# Zip compression using Spring Batch

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch

We are using Spring Batch in our project and have multiple jobs that each is responsible for exporting objects to xml.

We would like to choose from controller which objects are going to be exported by using checkboxes, and after sending request, these generated xml files should be compressed to ZIP file.

Does anybody have idea how to reach that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Once you defined the job that generates the XML file(s) of selected objects, you can add a step at the end of that job that compresses the generated file(s). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not completely. Every entity has its own configuration class with steps, jobs etc. 
That would work in that case only for zipping one type of object :(
Probably my question wasn't asked clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! Don't know why, but I didn't come up with this idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a job of jobs thanks to the [`JobStep`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html) class. Since you have a job for each entity (as explained in comments), you can create a job of jobs and add the compression step at its end to compress all generated files.

Hope this helps.